# OutOfMemoryExceptions on Productions Servers

Tags: java, tomcat

Can the following code snippets leak memory

A

```
BufferedWriter logoutput;
FileWriter fstream = null;
try {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FILE_FORMAT_NOW);
    fstream = new FileWriter("..\\GetInfoLogs\\" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + ".log", true);

    logoutput = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    logoutput.write(statement);
    // Missing fstream.close();
    logoutput.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to write to file");
}
```

B

```
    String info[] = {"", ""};
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select ....");

        boolean hasRows = rset.next();
        if (!hasRows) {
            stmt.close();
            return info;
        } else {
            info[0] = rset.getString(1);
            info[1] = rset.getString(2);
        }
        // MISSING rset.close();
        stmt.close();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logTransaction(service, "error at getPFpercentage: " + e.getMessage() + " ");

    }
```

Comment: Yes, but you should really use some profiler to find out exactly which part of your code is using the memory. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html is a good place to start

Comment: You should also set up heap dump on OOM - it can help a lot to be able to do a post mortem using EMA.

Comment: If a resource is not closed, the garbage collector won't pick it up. These accumulate and eventually fill up the heap throwing a OOM Error. Note: Its an Error and not a Exception, so you shouldn't try to handle it (especially as its a subclass of VirtualMachineError). You should, like mentioned above, profile your code and determine what resources are not closed and appropriately close them to allow the gc to do its job. Do **not** use a try-catch block to handle it.

Comment: I've heard that JDK 7 automatically closes the un-closed resources?

Comment: Well... JDK 7 introduces the feature of "try-with-resources" where it will close anything you haven't closed for you **IF** you choose the use that feature. First of all the resource must implement the AutoCloseable interface. Secondly, the try with resources syntax must be used. E.g: try(FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputSream()){ //Your code here }catch(IOException ex){//Handle code here...}. Using the plain old try{}catch(){} won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend use [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/index.jsp), as it very intuitive and easy to use tool.

Start your application locally, connect profiler to it and perform some of your application use cases.

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't.

Objects are collected by the garbage collector when there are no longer any live references to them in a program. This is in general unrelated to whether they have been closed.

The only way closing an object (or calling any other method on it) could affect its eligibility for collection was if there was some global structure which held a reference to the object, and closing it had the side effect of removing it from this structure. I am not aware of any such structure in the JDK's IO libraries. Indeed, IO classes in the JDK are generally designed to close themselves when they get garbage collected, which would be pretty futile if their being open prevented them being collected.

Database classes like `Connection`s are a bit trickier, because the have implementations provided by the JDBC driver. It is possible a poorly-written JDBC driver would prevent unclosed objects being collected. It seems unlikely, though, as that would be a huge screwup, frankly.

You can use the JDK's [`jmap`](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2006/03/08/java-memory-profiling-with-jmap-and-jhat) tool to get a heap dump of a running application. You can then analyse this to try to work out why your application is using so much memory. Be warned that the dump files are huge (bigger than the dumped heap), and analysing them is a real pain. A colleague of mine has got good results using the Eclipse [Memory Analyzer plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).